# Dent on aluminium frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, mechanical, accidents, framebuilding

I have a Cube Stereo 120 2018. When I was driving today a car hit me. I'm fine but the bike has a dent in it made by the car door.

1. Can it be fixed?
2. Can I still ride it, and go MTB?
3. Can I make a sort of modification, reinforcing the frame from outside?

Pictures:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without actually touching it, but the dent doesn't appear to create a significant structural hazard.  I'd just watch it for any signs of cracking.

Comment: And I would wash the bike in order to get a better view on its whole surface. Maybe there are additional cracks somewhere on the frame, currently hidden among the mud spots.

Comment: Since the _driver_ of a car hit you with the car, it is not your business to check if the damage is structural. Ask a bike shop who evaluates the damage to bikes. Let them do it and add the bill for the evaluation, plus the value loss of the bike, plus repairs to your claim against that driver (or their insurance).

Comment: @gschenk - Not all car vs bicycle accidents are the car drivers fault. Good advice presuming the car driver was in the wrong.

Comment: In many jurisdictions, (the more enlightened ones?) the default assumption when a motor vehicle hits a pedestrian or cyclist is that the driver is at fault.  I agree with that default assumption.

Comment: A dent on the right side of a bicycle made by a car door sounds a lot like the car driver’s (or rear passenger’s) fault. OP probably got [doored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dooring).

Comment: I wouldn't be confident riding that frame. Stand up an empty aluminum soda can, put your foot on top of it. You can put quite a bit of weight on that can before it collapses. Now, while you're putting that weight on that can, carefully reach down and tap the side of the can, just hard enough to put a small dent in it.  That can will immediately collapse. The strength of that can - and your downtube - comes from the shape distributing forces uniformly.  Even a small dent causes concentrations of force that are more than the thin-walled tube can withstand. You now have a dent in your can.

Comment: @Micheal  While it is well known in cycling circles that t cyclists are demi-gods that can do no wrong  not all road users are aware of this. Our community would be better respected on and off the road if we refrained from apportioning blame to car drivers until the facts are known until we have better educated all roads users so they understand the infallibility of cyclists. .

Comment: If the driver has accepted liability OP should press for a replacement through the driver's insurance since a structurally vital part is damaged.

Answer (score 5):

This is only engineering judgement, not technical analysis: the damage does not appear particularly serious or significant at that location. As Daniel advises above, keep an eye on it for cracks developing. If you are just a "normal" everyday type user it could be OK for quite a while. The Al frame will eventually crack and fail, not necessarily at this location. If you are a strong hard core competitor, then you wouldn't even consider using it for highly demanding duties would you?

Comment: Concur - add it to the monthly maintenance routine.  Take a photo monthly, and check for changes over time.  When it does start to change noticeably, stop riding it and reevaluate.